# VB.NET - Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row

Tags: vb.net

This is my Delete button code. When I click on the Delete button, it displays the error message "Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row." So, what will be the possible solution?

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If (i < ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1) Then
        Dim r1 As DataRow
        'r1 = ds.Tables(0).NewRow(i)(0)
        'r1.Delete()
        'Me.da.Update(ds.Tables(0))
        ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Delete()
        ds.Tables(0).GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)
        'ds.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
        'ds.AcceptChanges()
        'Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("cust_id")).ToString()
        'Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("cust_id"))
        Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))
        '  Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables(0))
        ' ds.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()

        i = i + 1
        TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("cust_id").ToString()
        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("fname").ToString()
        TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("sname").ToString()
        TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("lname").ToString()
        TextBox5.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("address").ToString()
        TextBox6.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("city").ToString()
        TextBox7.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("state").ToString()
        TextBox8.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("contact1").ToString()
        TextBox9.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("contact2").ToString()
        TextBox10.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("email").ToString()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, what is `ds` and `da`? Second, put a break point at the beginning of the function and step through the code to find what line the error occurs at.

Comment: Try to reassign ds after deletion ..

Answer (score 0):

You have the data shown in a grid or another control and when you delete it, the information is refreshed on the screen and this is when the control throws the error that the information cannot be accessed.

Before you delete a row in your table, you need to make sure it is removed from any UI elements, like binding sources or grids.